# Performance Of Multiple Pages In Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I am new to Flutter and when I was trying to find a way to add multiple pages, I found the Navigator.pop() and the .push() method. Apparently they load all widgets from all pages and then just displays them on top of each other. Surely that would mean awful performance since all pages are loaded at all times?

Is there a better way of making multiple pages or does it not impact performance a noticeable amount?

I was expecting there to be a way to add a new page to the screen by itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the **Navigator.pop()** and **Navigator.push()** methods are used for navigation between different pages or screens. but , they don't load all the widgets from all pages at once, instead, Flutter uses a widget tree and only builds the widgets that are currently needed or visible on the screen. This helps in optimizing performance by rendering only the relevant parts of the widget tree.

When you push a new page onto the navigation stack using Navigator.push(), Flutter adds the new page to the top of the stack, and only the widgets of the current top page are actively built and rendered. When you pop a page using Navigator.pop(), the top page is removed from the stack, and the previous page becomes the top page, with its widgets being rebuilt and displayed.

Flutter's widget tree architecture and the way it handles navigation make it efficient in terms of performance. The framework ensures that only the widgets on the current visible page are built and displayed.

If you're concerned about performance, it's essential to optimize your widget tree and make efficient use of state management to minimize unnecessary rebuilds

those methods are an efficient way to handle navigation between pages, and it does not necessarily impact performance negatively if implemented and optimized properly.